# How to structure a Python package so others can add modules easily

Tags: python, module, package

I have a component-oriented Python (3.3) project.  I have a base `Component` class.  I want others to be able to add modules that contain subclasses of `Component` just by copying their `.py` file(s) into some folder, without having to edit anything.  Running the main program should then simply import all the `.py` files found in that folder.  All accesses from my main program to these subclasses are via `Component.__subclasses__()`, not by explicit name.  I am not especially worried about name clashes between code in different user-written modules, but of course I would like to avoid it if possible without screwing up the simple drop-file-into-folder inclusion.

How do I structure a package to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

I would structure the package like this:

```
myPackage
+ -- __init__.py
+ -- Component.py
+ -- user_defined_packages
     + -- __init__.py # 1
     + -- example.py
```

Ideas:

1. let the users drop into a different folder so that they do not mix up your code and theirs
2. The init file in `user_defined_packages` can load all the subpackages once `user_defined_packages` is imported. It must print all errors.

`__init__.py` # 1

```
import os
import traceback
import sys

def import_submodules():
    def import_submodule(name):
        module_name = __name__ + '.' + name
        try:
            __import__(module_name)
        except:
            traceback.print_exc() # no error should pass silently
        else:
            module = sys.modules[module_name]
            globals()[name] = module # easier access

    directory = os.path.dirname(__file__)
    for path_name in os.listdir(directory):
        path = os.path.join(directory, path_name)
        if path_name.startswith('_'):
            # __pycache__, __init__.py and others
            continue
        if os.path.isdir(path):
            import_submodule(path_name)
        if os.path.isfile(path):
            name, extension = os.path.splitext(path_name)
            if extension in ('.py', '.pyw'):
                import_submodule(name)

import_submodules()
```